# UPPER operator in mysql does not convert the contents

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am using the `UPPER` operator in a query in mysql and instead of converting the contents of the table for that field to upper case, it only matches my query against rows that already have the content for that field in upper case.

For example, if I have a field named `category` and two rows, one with *Indian* and another with *INDIAN*, I am issuing a query as:

```
select * from table where UPPER(category) like '%INDIAN%'
```

and only the row with the field *INDIAN* in all upper case gets answered.

How do I issue a query where the query is case insensitive?

Comment: `UPPER()` is a function, not an operator; `LIKE` should be case-insensitive already. From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like): *The ... statements illustrate that string comparisons are not case sensitive unless one of the operands is a binary string ...*

Comment: Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/511415/2

Comment: @Jared has nicely explained your problem. Note that the `WHERE` clause only determines which rows are output. The actual values output are determined in the `SELECT *`. If you wrote `select UPPER(category) from table where category like '%indian%'` it would have returned the values in uppercase.

Comment: Your query should work for both upper and lower case.